# Java shortest path

Tags: java, algorithm, shortest-path

I'm trying to make an small tower defender game in Java. I have a grid that is made up of a `Point2D.Double` array named:

FieldArr[h][v]

`h` represents horizontal fields, `v` the vertical vertical fields

this makes a grid like this

```
+ + + + + + +
S + X + + + +
+ + + X + + +
+ X + + + + F
+ + X + + + +
```

S represents start, F represents Finish, X represents Towers

now I want to calculate the shortest route for but i don't have any clue how to start on this

Towers have the following vars for location:
HorizontalNr and VerticalNr.

for paint I do then:

```
public void paint(Graphics2D g2) {
    int Xpos = HorizontalNr * playfield.getSquarewidth() + playfield.GetinitialXPos();
    int Ypos = VerticalNr * playfield.getSquarewidth() + playfield.GetinitialYPos();
    g2.fillRect(Xpos, Ypos, 50, 50);
}
```

Anyone have any tips, on how I should make my enemy class, so I won't get in any problem with the algorithm?
and/or have tips on how to calculate the shortest path?

already thanks
grt kiwi

Comment: Shortest route to do what? Are you trying to solve travelling salesman?

Comment: Shortest route from start to finish while avoiding the towers

Comment: And be careful of how you do your comparisons, especially if you want towers to block enemies - Double/Float values are not 'exact'.  Depending on your exact need, you may need to create your own `Point` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark said, this is Shortest Path Problem, which can be solved easily and efficiently.

Note, that since your problem is not weighted, you can use a [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) here, which is pretty easy to implement and also guarantees finding sortest path for unweighted graphs.

Pseudo code for BFS:

```
findShortestPath(source,target):
  queue<- new queue
  visited <- {}
  Map<point,point> parents <- empty map
  queue.push(source)
  while (queue.empty() == false): 
     current <- queue.takeFirst()
     if (current.equals(target)):
         extract the path from source to destination using the map parents(*)
         return
     visited.add(current)
     for each p such that p and current are neighbors: //insert neighbors to queue
          if p is not in visited: 
                if (p is not an obstacle):
                   queue.push(p)
                   parents.put(p,current) //current is the parent of p
```

(*) Extracting the path from the map is simple: just follow the `current <- parent.get(current)` until you get `null`, this way you extract the exact path you will use.

Note that even faster solution [in most cases] will be [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) with the [manhattan distance heuristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry), but it is much more complex to implement it.

Comment: Hmm gonna look in to this, looks definitively easier ^^

Comment: But how could I define let's say the source (in java)?
I can give the horizontalnr and vertical nr, but I don't know how I could put that in 1 var

Comment: @Kiwi The source is the input to any shortest path problem - it is the start of the path, or in tower defense games: "where enemies enter the map from"

Comment: I know, but I cant say
point2D start = point2D(x,y)

my start is like = start[1][1] and that is an block of 50x50, so should I calculate the centers, and use them?

Comment: @Kiwi: I don't follow. `sorce` is `S` in your example and `target` is `F` in your example.

Comment: Yea, and each block, has an Horizontal nr and vertical nr.

S = 1 block, F = 1 block, Tower = 1 block, ...

Comment: @Kiwi: In this case: you can take the center and check for collisions. You also need to take care you move on blocks [and not partial blocks].An alternative [better one in my opinion] is to create a "minimap" which contains all the detail but each block will be at size 1. Use the algorithm on this minimap

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, thanks! I was using my own recursive Dijkstra implementation but it was really ineficient! This is much faster.

Answer (score 4):

The [shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) has been studied a lot and a lot of literature exists on this problem. It's probably best to just using an existing algorithm rather than trying to invent an algorithm yourself.

For example, a simple and efficient algorithm is [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). From Wikipedia:

> 1. Let the node at which we are starting be called the initial node. Let the distance of node Y be the distance from the initial node to Y. Dijkstra's algorithm will assign some initial distance values and will try to improve them step by step.
>      Assign to every node a tentative distance value: set it to zero for our initial node and to infinity for all other nodes.
> 2. Mark all nodes unvisited. Set the initial node as current. Create a set of the unvisited nodes called the unvisited set consisting of all the nodes except the initial node.
> 3. For the current node, consider all of its unvisited neighbors and calculate their tentative distances. For example, if the current node A is marked with a tentative distance of 6, and the edge connecting it with a neighbor B has length 2, then the distance to B (through A) will be 6+2=8. If this distance is less than the previously recorded tentative distance of B, then overwrite that distance. Even though a neighbor has been examined, it is not marked as visited at this time, and it remains in the unvisited set.
> 4. When we are done considering all of the neighbors of the current node, mark the current node as visited and remove it from the unvisited set. A visited node will never be checked again; its distance recorded now is final and minimal.
> 5. If the destination node has been marked visited (when planning a route between two specific nodes) or if the smallest tentative distance among the nodes in the unvisited set is infinity (when planning a complete traversal), then stop. The algorithm has finished.
> 6. Set the unvisited node marked with the smallest tentative distance as the next "current node" and go back to step 3.

Comment: I know the algorythm, but I don't realy know how to implement it,

Comment: @Kiwi: There's some [pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode) on the Wikipedia page. You can use that as a basis for your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

if you're looking to avoid the towers then your looking for the euclidean path from start to finish, which is solvable with a shortest path approach ala djkstra.

Comment: You should add more details substantiating your answer, so OP could get a better idea of the problem.